# reorder the elements and also populate default output at same time

Tags: xslt

Need to reorder the elements and also populate default output at same time.

## Input is as below.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>
    <info>
        <data>  
             <age> 33 </age>
             <name>Student1  </name>
        </data> 
        <data>  
             <age> 44 </age>
             <name>Student2  </name>
        </data>
    </info>
```

## Output expected is as shown below.

```
NAME|HEIGHT|AGE|SALARY|COUNTRY
Student1||33||USA
Student2||44||USA
```

HEIGHT and  SALARY,COUNTRY are not part of input xml.
For HEIGHT and SALARY the outpt should be empty string "". 
Between elements it should be "|" separated.
Between each row it should be newline separated.

Default value of COUNTRY  is USA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:text>NAME|HEIGHT|AGE|SALARY|COUNTRY</xsl:text>

  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="data">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat('&#xA;', normalize-space(name),
          '||', normalize-space(age),'||USA')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<info>
    <data>
        <age> 33 </age>
        <name>Student1  </name>
    </data>
    <data>
        <age> 44 </age>
        <name>Student2  </name>
    </data>
</info>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
NAME|HEIGHT|AGE|SALARY|COUNTRY
Student1||33||USA
Student2||44||USA
```